# What technologies did the cybersuit in Star Kid have?

Tags: star-kid

I lost my VHS copy of the movie Star Kid, but I remember the Cybersuit being awesome. Does anybody know what kinda of technology it had? I know it had some kind of scanning device, something to replay the users memories and a laser type weapon, but does anyone know what the exact names the features were called? I think the laser weapon was a plasma blaster but I could be wrong